# Running Jupyter/IPython document on Zepplin

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter, apache-zeppelin

I have a large set of existing documents running on Jupyter.  I want to move to Zeppelin.

I assume Jupyter pages run in Zeppelin, but I can't find any documentation.  Has anyone tried this?  Does it work?  Anyone have a useful link?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter's ipynb is json file. You can find [The Jupyter Notebook Format](http://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Zeppelin's note.json is also json format. Each notebook has an folder(notebook id) and note.json.

It should be possible to convert with a small application. I think most important information shall be.

> cells(jupyter) -> paragraphs(Zeppelin)
>
> cell -> paragraph
>
> cell_type -> %... in text
>
> source -> text

Answer (score 6):

You can use the new "JupyterUtility" introduced by [Pull Request 2393](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2393) to convert one jupyter notebook (.ipynb) to apache zeppelin notebook (.json). It's not yet released and the documentation is still in progress (see [ZEPPELIN-2616](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2616)). But you can either take the 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT build or checkout the sources and build/use it with maven.

E.g.: checkout -> switch to folder "zeppelin-jupyter":

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.apache.zeppelin.jupyter.JupyterUtil" -Dexec.args="-i INPUTFILE.ipynb -o OUTPUTFILE.json"
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved in Zeppelin 0.10.0. This is the pull request closed [ZEPPELIN-3033](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3033)

Check the version at the menu "About Zepplin".

Go to "Import Note" from the main page

[image: zeppelin main page]

Then you can select the ipynb file to import.
[image: pop up import new note]

Maybe the interpreter won't be ok. You'd have to export the file, use a text editor to remplace all the interpreter by default and then import again.

If you are using Zeppelin with HortonWorks or Cloudera be careful. Zeppelin's version is 0.8.0. [Here is the doc](https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-apache-zeppelin.html)

Right now, I didn't find offical documentation about how to import a jupyter file into zeppelin. I think I doesn't exist because the pull request is open [ZEPPELIN-2616](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2616)